# Upgrading Ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 when 1.8.7 is not under rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have ruby 1.8.7 as the default version in my machine. The problem is it's not under RVM and switching to 1.9.3 does nothing.

How can I uninstall 1.8.7 and make 1.9.3 the default ruby version?

Comment: If you're on OS X, be very wary doing this.

Comment: We need more information about what happened when you switched to 1.9.3. Generally rvm does not care the old system ruby version.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. when I switched to 1.9.3  this message popped up-> Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0. but when I did ruby -v it was still 1.8.7

Comment: If ever. Is there any way to uninstall all of this? I'd rather start fresh to save time?

Comment: I'm on Debian and I remember having troubles with rvm, so I finally uninstalled rvm and switched using Debian 1.9.3 package :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies
   ruby-1.8.6-p420 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

$ rvm remove 1.8.7-p334

Removing /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p334...
Removing /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p334 aliases...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p334 wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p334 environments...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p334 binaries...

$ rvm use --default 1.9.3-p194

Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194

$ rvm list

rvm rubies
   ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
```

Use `rvmsudo rvm` if you installed RVM as root and want your changes to be reflected for all users.

Edit: I just realized you said 1.8.7 was on the system by default. Just install RVM as root and install 1.9.3, and set as default as I have described above using `rvmsudo`. Make sure you use the newest version of RVM. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What machine are you on? One way is `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`. If that doesn't work for you on the console, consider putting that on the last line of your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` -- Whichever shell you use.